# Accidentally deleted lots of things from root-direct(/), how to rescue?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, linux-mint

My laptop runs linux Mint 17.3.

I was coding, while there was a bug in target clean of my Makefile. As I run 'make clean'，GNUMake tries to delete everything from root-path(without sudo). I found and cancelled it instantly, but many things have gone.

I read (from many places including here Superuser) that it's impossible to undo rm, but I wanna if I can recovery my whole system without manual former backups?

My system's unstable now, maybe I should transfer my data and reinstall it :(

Comment: You could take a look at [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Without a backup, you're out of luck... If it's really valuable data you should turn off your system and bring it to a data recovery service.

Comment: Reinstall the system. Before, mount the drive on another system read only, search for methods able to extract the list of installed packages, go to create the list of installed packages, search instruction for ddrescue or similar to search among the deleted files. Reinstall the system (you cannot rely on recovered maybe partial files) and add what you really need from the old HDD. Good Luck. ps> __Backup__ and not only this time.

Comment: Thank u guys. As I don't know what's been deleted specifically, it may be hard to find them back. Fortunately, most of my data are still be here. As my system's unstable, I did just reboot and load with recovery mode, (cause I thought, no matter what, basically I can use the USB installer to run a OS and deal with the remain data), after a check, reboot, and the system works normal again. The only flaw is I have to resetup and reinstall something, luckily not the whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a long time on safe-removing(e.g. move in to a recycle-bin instead of removing), finally I decide to alias my `rm` to `rm -I`, as it's convenient and meanwhile safe.